# run the mysql with :"systemctl start mysqld.service " error

Tags: mysql, linux

when I start mysql in linux with:" systemctl start mysqld.service "
then hint:
Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
someone could hepl me ?thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Add the error details to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for no details about your error.

I suggest you that open the logs to see more details. In other words, you could use the command line `systemctl status mysqld.service` or `journalctl -xe`.(I have tried that, but it's useless, so I suggest you to read mysql-logs);

use this command

`cat /var/log/mysqld.log`

(you could use this command`find -name mysqld.log` in /root, if you could find the log in that directory).

I do that and find one [error]

> 2019-04-20T09:37:25.628853Z 0 [ERROR] unknown variable 'validate_password=off'
>
> 2019-04-20T09:37:25.628863Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

and then, I use command

`vim /etc/my.cnf`

and find this line"validate_password=off" and replace it with "# validate_password=off". And then exit vim.

Now, use this command

`service mysqld start`

and

`service mysqld status`

to see the status of mysql. Maybe there is a surprise  : )